# Sync listings caption numbers and add all to List of Listings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, captions, floatrow

I want to create a list of all listings. Listings itself allows to add captions and list them in a list using `\lstlistoflistings`, but they can not float. If I set up such a floating environment using `floatrow` they belong to a different list and the number of the caption is wrong. I would like to have the numbers correct in one numbering scheme and add both to the List of Listings.

The caption of the first one is "Listing 1: "

The caption of the second one is "Code 0.0.1: "

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\DeclareNewFloatType{Code}%
{placement=tbhp,within=section,fileext=loc}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={LaTeX Listings}]
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
Some text ...
\chapter{Theory}
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{Code}[H]
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[Visual]Basic}]
Sub Main()
    MsgBox "Hallo Welt!"
End Sub
\end{lstlisting}
  \caption{Hello World in Visual Basic 6}
  \label{lstLaTeXLinesOfCode2}
\end{Code}

\lstlistoflistings
\listof{Code}{List of Code listings}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) allows you to specify a `float=<spec>` key-value to allow the `lstlisting` to float so you don't need to make your own floating environment. Here, `<spec>` can any combination from `htbp`.

[image: Floating lstlisting]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
%\usepackage{floatrow}
%\DeclareNewFloatType{Code}%
%{placement=tbhp,within=section,fileext=loc}

\begin{document}

Here is some text.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={LaTeX Listings},float=t]
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
Some text ...
\chapter{Theory}
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

Here is some more text.

%\begin{Code}[H]
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Hello World in Visual Basic 6},label=lstLaTeXLinesOfCode2,language={[Visual]Basic},float=t]
Sub Main()
    MsgBox "Hallo Welt!"
End Sub
\end{lstlisting}
%  \caption{Hello World in Visual Basic 6}
%  \label{lstLaTeXLinesOfCode2}
%\end{Code}

Here is some more text, yet again.

\lstlistoflistings
%\listof{Code}{List of Code listings}

\end{document}​
```

See p 6 of the [`listings` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

Comment: This does not solve the wrong numbering in the floatrow code, but it provides the floating that I wanted. So in this case I do not need a new float.